# Is NPSHr dependant on temperature?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pumps

I know that net positive suction head available depends on temperature since viscosity, density and vapour pressure depends on temperature but how about NPSHr?
We know that the vapour pressure depends on temperature but does this affect the pressure of the pump's inlet at which cavitation occurs? if so what would be the overall effect?

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check out ISO 9906 Annex. H, Figure.H1

Comment: Please expand your answer to include the relevant information, at least the most essential points. Feel free to quote directly from the source.